# Cron Job - Magento - Reindexall not working

Tags: php, magento, ssh, cron

Been trying to figure this one out for hours...

I've got the cron setup, and it runs when it's suppose to.

```
36 22 * * * php -f /home/user/public_html/shop/shell/indexer.php --reindexall
```

Outputs

```
Error in argument 3, char 2: no argument for option -
Usage: php [-q] [-h] [-s] [-v] [-i] [-f <file>]
       php <file> [args...]
  -a               Run interactively
  -b <address:port>|<port> Bind Path for external FASTCGI Server mode
  -C               Do not chdir to the script's directory
  -c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory
  -n               No php.ini file will be used
  -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
  -e               Generate extended information for debugger/profiler
  -f <file>        Parse <file>.  Implies `-q'
  -h               This help
  -i               PHP information
  -l               Syntax check only (lint)
  -m               Show compiled in modules
  -q               Quiet-mode.  Suppress HTTP Header output.
  -s               Display colour syntax highlighted source.
  -v               Version number
  -w               Display source with stripped comments and whitespace.
  -z <file>        Load Zend extension <file>.
  -T <count>       Measure execution time of script repeated <count> times.
```

If I remove the --

```
36 22 * * * php -f /home/user/public_html/shop/shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

it outputs

```
Usage:  php -f indexer.php -- [options]

  --status <indexer>            Show Indexer(s) Status
  --mode <indexer>              Show Indexer(s) Index Mode
  --mode-realtime <indexer>     Set index mode type "Update on Save"
  --mode-manual <indexer>       Set index mode type "Manual Update"
  --reindex <indexer>           Reindex Data
  info                          Show allowed indexers
  reindexall                    Reindex Data by all indexers
  help                          This help

  <indexer>     Comma separated indexer codes or value "all" for all indexers
```

If I run the same command in SSH it works perfectly fine... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the command arguments behind the `--`:

```
36 22 * * * php -f /home/user/public_html/shop/shell/indexer.php -- --reindexall
```

as manual page for `php` suggests:

```
php [options] [ -f ] file [[--] args...]
```

Otherwise `php` is trying to parse these arguments as its own and fails.

Comment: Yes.  The 1st error indicates that PHP isn't happy with the arguments.  The 2nd error is from indexer and shows that the options must follow '-- '.  That's two minuses and a space.

Comment: so does it work for you or not? If not, what is the actual question?

Comment: I've tried multiple variations. It simply will not accept arguments before and after for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I could figure out was...

Create a PHP file that forces the Magento model to re-index it's self

```
//
// Initiate Magento MAGE
//

$mage_php_url = "app/Mage.php";
// Include Magento's Mage.php file.
require_once($mage_php_url);

/* @var $indexCollection Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Process_Collection */
$indexCollection = Mage::getModel('index/process')->getCollection();
foreach ($indexCollection as $index) {
    /* @var $index Mage_Index_Model_Process */
    $index->reindexAll();
}

echo "<h1>Re-Index Completed.</h1>";
```

After setup cron job to run this simple PHP file.